# Show help for my Gtkmm application without Autotools or Meson

Tags: c++, gtk, gnome, gtkmm, mallard

I have written a small application using Gtkmm for which I would like to provide documentation for users. For this, I would like to launch the [Gnome help system](https://developer.gnome.org/platform-overview/unstable/dev-help.html.en) from my application's menu (For a working example, one can look at [gedit](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit)).

First, I wrote a minimal Mallard `index.page` file:

```xml
<page xmlns="http://projectmallard.org/1.0/"
      type="guide"
      id="index">
<title>Example help</title>
</page>
```

which I can view by calling the command `yelp help/C/index.page` from my project's root directory:

[image: Basic help from yelp]

Then, I wrote some minimal C++ application (Gtkmm 3.22) to call the help system:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm.h>

constexpr char HELP_URI[] = "help:myapp";

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "bob.morane.question");

    Gtk::Window window;

    // 1. Add the help menu item:
    Gtk::MenuItem helpItem;
    helpItem.set_label("Help");

    Gtk::Menu helpMenu;
    Gtk::MenuItem openHelpItem;
    openHelpItem.set_label("Open help...");

    Gtk::MenuBar menuBar;
    menuBar.append(helpItem);
    helpItem.set_submenu(helpMenu);
    helpMenu.append(openHelpItem);

    window.add(menuBar);
    

    // 2. Link the help menu item to Mallard documentation:
    openHelpItem.signal_activate().connect([&window](){
        const guint32 timestamp = gtk_get_current_event_time();
        GError* error = nullptr;

        // This is the call that triggers gnome help system:
        const bool status = gtk_show_uri_on_window (window.gobj(),
                                                    HELP_URI,
                                                    timestamp,
                                                    &error);
        if(!status)
        {
            std::cout << "Unable to show help : " + std::string{error->message} << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    });

    window.show_all();
    return app->run(window);
}
```

which I build using a very simple Makefile:

```
all: main.cpp
    g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -o myapp `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

When I click on the `Open help...` menu item, I get the following:

[image: Not found]

If I change my program's first line to: `constexpr char HELP_URI[] = "help:gedit";`, then the gedit help pops out fine. Using a build system such as Meson (like gedit) or Autotools  (like this [Gnome documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/platform-overview/unstable/dev-help-build.html.en) suggests) would be overkill for me right now. I would like to be able to show my help file without the need to handle those (i.e. I want to keep using my Makefile).

*Question: How could I show my own help file without needing to use Meson or Autotools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The help files have to be somewhere Yelp can find them. Usually you would install them to `/usr/share/help/LANG/APPID/`, where `LANG` is a language identifier (or just `C` for the untranslated docs), and `APPID` is some identifier for your app (matching the basename of your `.desktop` file is a good best practice).

If you use autotools, `yelp.m4` takes care of all of this for you: http://yelp.io/tools/yelp.m4

If you use meson, the `gnome.yelp` function takes care of this for you: https://mesonbuild.com/Gnome-module.html#gnomeyelp

But if you don't want to use a build system, you'll have to manage getting the files somewhere yourself. They don't have to be in `/usr/`. Yelp looks in the `help` subdirectory of the directories in `$XDG_DATA_HOME` and `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` from the XDG base directory specification. By default, this means it looks at `~/.local/share/help/:/usr/local/share/help/:/usr/share/help/`. So you can install the files locally under `~/.local/share/` for testing purposes.

Or, if you really don't want to install files anywhere, you can arrange your source tree in a specific way and set an environment variable. For example, if your source tree is rooted at `~/myapp/`, then put your page files under `~/myapp/help/C/myapp/`, and call your app with `XDG_DATA_HOME=~/myapp/ myapp`.

But really, if you want users to use your app, you're going to have to figure out how to install files in the right places. And you're better off using an existing build system for that, even if you think your app is too small.

Comment: I will definitely try this out tonight. I had a really hard time getting this kind of information online. Out of curiosity, where did you find this information (e.g. where yelp looks, which variable to set, etc.)?

Comment: I found the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) explaining how this variable works. I had no idea this was used behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing: since I cannot move to a build system just yet, I decided to write a small script to copy my help contents to `~/.local/share` for testing purposes:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

TARGET=~/.local/share

if [[ -d "${TARGET}/" ]]
then
    cp -r ./help ${TARGET}
else
    echo "Error: ${TARGET} does not exist."
fi
```

With this I am able to develop my help documentation without having to use a build system just yet. Note that for this script to work, I have added my `index.page` help file under `help/C/myapp/index.page` from my project's root directory. This allows me to automate this script from my Makefile, so I don't have to copy everything by hand or call Yelp myself:

```
all: main.cpp
    ./installHelp.sh
    g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -o myapp `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

As Shaun McCance mentionned however, this solution is not portable and sooner or later I will have to move to some build system.